# Bulk insert in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, csv, bulk

I have created SSIS package that imports data to my table from csv, I am trying to reproduce SSIS via sql command, more specifically, with bulk insert statement, could you help?

csv file properties:

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 7):

You can use `Bulk Insert` for the purpose:

```
BULK INSERT table_name
FROM 'c:\test.csv'
WITH
(
   FIRSTROW= 3,
   FIELDTERMINATOR = ';',
   ROWTERMINATOR = '\n'
)
```

Comment: Unfortunately, this doesn't work in my case. Perhaps, other properties should be provided...not sure...

Answer (score 1):

Followng is not using bulk insert command – but using `SqlBulkCopy` class in `.Net` for `SSIS` script task

Following is the `script task` for copying data from one table into it’s history database (in another server) using Bulk Copy approach inside SSIS Script task. It uses `ADO Connection` in SSIS.

Import Namespaces

```
Imports System
Imports System.Data
Imports System.Data.Sql
Imports System.Data.SqlClient

Imports System.Math
Imports System.IO
Imports Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Runtime
Imports System.Windows.Forms
```

**CODE**

```
 Public Sub PerformBulkCopy(ByVal tableName As String, ByVal sourceConnection As SqlConnection, ByVal destinationConnection As SqlConnection)
    Dim dtSource As DataTable
    dtSource = New System.Data.DataTable()
    dtSource = GetSourceDataTable(tableName, sourceConnection)


    Using sbc As New SqlBulkCopy(destinationConnection)
        sbc.DestinationTableName = tableName
        sbc.WriteToServer(dtSource)
    End Using
End Sub


Public Function GetSourceDataTable(ByVal tableName As String, ByVal sourceConnection As SqlConnection) As DataTable

    Dim cmd As New SqlCommand("uspGetDataForAchival")
    cmd.Parameters.Add(New SqlParameter("@TableName", tableName))
    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure
    cmd.Connection = sourceConnection

    Dim dap As New SqlDataAdapter(cmd)
    Dim ds As New DataSet()
    dap.Fill(ds)
    Return ds.Tables(0)

End Function

Public Sub Main()

    Dim tableName As String = Dts.Variables("User::CurrentTable").Value.ToString()
    Dim sourceConnection As SqlConnection
    Dim destinationConnection As SqlConnection

    Try
        ' Retrieve the reference to the managed connection'
        Dim cmSource As ConnectionManager
        cmSource = Dts.Connections("ADOSourceConnection")
        sourceConnection = DirectCast(cmSource.AcquireConnection(Dts.Transaction), System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection)

        Dim cmDestination As ConnectionManager
        cmDestination = Dts.Connections("ADOACIConnection")
        destinationConnection = DirectCast(cmDestination.AcquireConnection(Dts.Transaction), System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection)

        Dim destinationConnectionString As String = destinationConnection.ConnectionString
        MessageBox.Show(destinationConnectionString)
        PerformBulkCopy(tableName, sourceConnection, destinationConnection)

        'Release Connection'
        cmSource.ReleaseConnection(sourceConnection)
        cmDestination.ReleaseConnection(destinationConnection)

        'Success'
        Dts.TaskResult = Dts.Results.Success


    Catch ex As Exception

        Dim exceptionVariable As Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Runtime.Variables = Nothing
        Dts.VariableDispenser.LockOneForWrite("User::ScriptException", exceptionVariable)
        exceptionVariable("User::ScriptException").Value = ex.Message
        exceptionVariable.Unlock()
        Dts.Events.FireError(-1, "Task Name", ex.Message, String.Empty, 0)
        Dts.TaskResult = Dts.Results.Failure
     End Try

    End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this piece of code

```
StreamReader file = new StreamReader(bulk_data_filename);
CsvReader csv = new CsvReader(file, true,',');
SqlBulkCopy copy = new SqlBulkCopy(conn);
copy.DestinationTableName = tablename;
copy.WriteToServer(csv);
```